# Getting a handle to dojo's uploader filelist

Tags: file-upload, dojo

We are using `dojo's` `dojox.form.uploader.FileList` in our application to show the progress of file upload. But it shows the name of the file, type extension by default. We could not see any settings to hide it or getting a handle to that. Is it possible to get a handle to that object which has file name, size and extension? Could you please help us?